# NLog configuration.Install() hides all errors

Tags: .net, logging, nlog, trace

I have a database target in my NLog.config with `install-command` element:

```xml
 <install-command ignoreFailures="false">
    <commandType>Text</commandType>
    <text>
        table create statement WITH ERRORS!
    </text>
  </install-command>
```

The configuration file is read automatically and then I call targets initialization like this:

```
var ctx = new InstallationContext();
ctx.IgnoreFailures = false;
LogManager.Configuration.Install(ctx);
```

It runs without any exceptions! Why?? Took me hours to investigate what's wrong.

Moreover, if I enable NLog internal logging with Trace level I see this:

```
2016-11-03 12:55:14.5498 Info NLog internal logger initialized.
2016-11-03 12:55:14.5498 Debug Loading config from C:\Projects\myapp\bin\NLog.config
2016-11-03 12:55:14.5633 Trace ParseNLogElement
```

and that's it. It looks absolutely useless. What the purpose of that internal logging?

Comment: Which NLog version is this?

Comment: The latest one, 4.3.10.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Installing-targets#installation-log and https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging